# Ghostscript - Convert vector pdf to the raster pdf

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, rasterize

I would like to convert the vector pdf to raster pdf by using ghostscript(i.e. rasterized the vector pdf). But I cannot find the appropriate parameters to do so even if I add the resolution parameter -r300.

The code I used is `-dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dGrap
hicsAlphaBits=1 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -r300 -sOutputFile="output-raster.pdf" "input-vector.pdf"`

Anyone know how to rasterized the pdf?

Comment: Use Ghostscript to save to a raster format and pipe that back to Ghostscript to convert back to pdf. Or just use Imagemagick, since it always rasterizes an input PDF.

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to convert it by using ghostscript only. Any idea? or It is impossible for doing so by using ghostscript?

Comment: @CAL Any idea on this? Same problem here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compressing text heavy PDFs without ghostscript and only ImageMagik causes blurry text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160191/compressing-text-heavy-pdfs-without-ghostscript-and-only-imagemagik-causes-blurr)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pdftocairo` from the Poppler library. It can convert a PDF to a raster image format like PNG or JPEG. Then use any image viewer or imagemagick to convert the image to a PDF file if you need a PDF as output.

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to convert it by using ghostscript only. Any idea? or It is impossible for doing so by using ghostscript?